# Make a home massage bed alternative without drilling a hole in the bed?

Tags: home, comfort, bedroom

For a professional massage, a massage bed with a hole for facing down and breathing is used. Is there any way to make one for our bed without drilling a face hole? For example, I tried to use an airplane travel neck pillow, but it fails because my mouth and nose touch the bed and I cannot breathe. Is there any way to solve it with everyday objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you place a chair next to the bed and roll or stack towels or pillows to match the bed height? Then rest your forehead on the chair.

Comment: Thank you very much. Rolling a towel is a good idea. I will try it.

Comment: For rolling a towel, height and stiffness can be adjusted. I will try it.